# Efficient way to copy/sync a table - ideas on different approaches

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have an ISV database which we try to minimize contact with. It is an old `2008 R2` DB. We want to keep a copy of a number of tables in a different database. We are looking for a T-SQL solution to sync tables. This may need to take place when the system is being used.

I appreciate the answer will require further research and testing.

- These tables are prone to locking from ISV app.
- This is a low powered server and not really Enterprise.
- Also we think the number of tables that we sync will increase
- We want avoid anything like replication (the supplier of the ISV has habit of blaming any issues on us with no investigation whatsoever!)

These are my options (the ones I've thought of)

- I've read bad things about MERGE in terms of performance, bearing in mind it's an older db, would this be fair?
- tablediff.exe would be perfect but I'm concerned about locking the source table.
- Is a straight truncate/insert with minimal locking/logging very inefficient - sounds stupid but I thought I'd include it.

Would just truncating and inserting a couple

Comment: How many rows are you expecting to be updated / inserted / deleted with a MERGE? How many rows should the table hold in total?

Comment: I would still go with replication, it is ideal for what you need to do. Anything else will introduce its own issues and administrative overhead, scheduling of sync's etc.

Comment: If load on source machine for full extract is small, do consider drop all indexes + truncate/load. It will be efficient for small tables. I am working on a similar solution at the moment. Please give more info about number of tables/rows and date/datetime fields available in all/some tables.

Comment: A lot of this will depend on what percentage of the data is going to change between sync's.  If the percentage is high, truncate/load may be your best bet.

Comment: Hi the data is small-ish - couple of 100,000 rows. The data won't massively change between sync. Unless I am missing something, replication won't work as we would have to configure the source database. We only really have SELECT access.

Comment: That already limits what solution you can put in place. Either a clever SSIS process, or some MERGE t-sql scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You have many options, depending on what you want to achieve and the constraints you have on the source/copy database:

- **Merge Replication**: can be bi-directional. Can be filtered and implement complex `JOIN` filters. The subscriber database is writable. Needs to have a `rowguidcol` on each table (`uniqueidentifier UNIQUE NOT NULL ROWGUIDCOL` column), so it can be a deal breaker if you can't touch the schema of the source database. Ships incremental changes quite efficiently.
- **Snapshot replication**: uni-directional. Can be filtered. The subscriber database is writable. No schema changes needed. Doesn't ship incremental changes: it's all or nothing.
- **Transactional Replication**: can be bi-directional (but updateable subscriptions is deprecated and needs an additional column on each updateable article. Peer-to-peer is enterprise-only, so I'm mentioning it so that you know it exists, but it won't work for you). Can have static filters. Every table needs to have a `PRIMARY KEY` defined, which is not typically the case in ugly, hairy, legacy third-party applications.
- **Mirroring**: the database at the mirror server can be read from a snapshot, which is an Enterprise features, unless you use SQL Server 2016 SP1 or later, where snapshots have been included in all editions. Wouldn't work for HA, just for scale-out. Uni-directional, no filters, no schema changes needed. The snapshot is a static copy of the data at a given time, so you need to take snapshots at different times to see new data. This means you have to kill connections to older snapshots before you create the new one.
- **Log Shipping**: can be used to obtain a read-only copy of the primary database by using `RESTORE WITH STANDBY`. Needs to kill all connections before restoring additional t-logs. No filters, no schema changes needed. Interferes with existing transaction log backup schedules.
- **Custom sync process**: you could combine different techniques to build your own sync process, but I really advise against that. The complexities are countless and it's hard to outsmart existing scale-out or data distribution tecnhnologies built in the product.

Comment: Log-shipping sounds an option, I'm a dev not a DBA. It's an odd situation. We want to limit ourselves to SELECT on the ISV database - we feel that minimizes political issues with the supplier. But we have full admin rights to the box. It is 2008 R2 standard. Could we log ship to a SQL Express server, or another database on the server without a major performance hit on the ISV database. Ideally every hour. If so I'd be happy to investigate that.

Comment: You can't log ship to SQL Express. You didn't mention if the "copied" data on destination needs to be READ ONLY, or if you need to be able to modify it?

Comment: @user1102550 wait. if your only concern is having read-only access to the database, you're looking at the problem in a complicated way. Revoke yourself the sysadmin privileges and use a dedicated windows or SQL login for managing the server, grant yourself `SELECT` permissions only, so that accidental updates won't occur.

Comment: @HenricoBekker you **can** ship logs to an Express Edition, it's just that you can't do it with SQLAgent jobs. Here's an alternative method with powershell: https://spaghettidba.com/2013/02/08/manual-log-shipping-with-powershell/

Comment: @spaghettidba that's a good alternative, although not what I meant with my post. OP is not a DBA, not sure this will be a viable path to explore.

Comment: Although not a DBA, I'm turning into an accidental sys-admin! One thing I need to learn is Powershell, so this might be a good fit. So just to clarify:
I can ship the log of Standard 2008 R2 server to SQL Express to create a read only copy. Will this "log-ship" say every hour interfere with any current backups. This would be worth investigation. In my head having a readonly copy of the db which I can tablediff on for further syncing would be perfect.

Comment: Yes, depending on what other backups run, making a second set of log backups will interfere with the primary backup process log sequence chain. If you do go this route, you'll need all log backups when you need to perform a restore, this might get tricky. This part in the PS solution will need to be adapted for the restore option:  $SQL_RestoreDatabase = "
            RESTORE LOG $DatabaseName
            FROM DISK='$RemoteBackupPath'
            WITH STANDBY;

Comment: If you're going to use PowerShell to roll your own log shipping, you can use your existing transaction log backups and just use PowerShell to restore them to your Express edition box.